# User warning when exporting Pytorch model to ONNX

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, onnx

I have found some code that directly converts the pytorch model to onnx:

```py
import torch.onnx  
torch.onnx.export(
    model,  
    input,  
    "model.onnx",  
    export_params=True,  
    opset_version=10
)
```

But it throws UserWarning most of the time :-

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2359: UserWarning: **floordiv** is deprecated, and its behavior will change in a future version of pytorch. It currently rounds toward 0 (like the 'trunc' function NOT 'floor'). This results in incorrect rounding for negative values. To keep the current behavior, use torch.div(a, b, rounding_mode='trunc'), or for actual floor division, use torch.div(a, b, rounding_mode='floor').

_verify_batch_size([input.size(0) * input.size(1) // num_groups, num_groups] + list(input.size()[2:]))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset9.py:1934: UserWarning: ONNX export unsqueeze with negative axis -1 might cause the onnx model to be incorrect. Negative axis is not supported in ONNX. Axis is converted to 1 based on input shape at export time. Passing an tensor of different rank in execution will be incorrect.

"Passing an tensor of different rank in execution will be incorrect.")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset9.py:1934: UserWarning: ONNX export unsqueeze with negative axis -1 might cause the onnx model to be incorrect. Negative axis is not supported in ONNX. Axis is converted to 2 based on input shape at export time. Passing an tensor of different rank in execution will be incorrect.

"Passing an tensor of different rank in execution will be incorrect.")

Can you explain why I am getting this error and is this method correct for exporting to onnx or can you suggest any better method for exporting complex pytorch model to onnx ?

Comment: Hi. A warning is not an error, it is just a warning that something _could_ go wrong. In the context of model conversion, this warning tells that maybe things go unexpected because your model uses an operation that is unknown to ONNX. Can you elaborate on the result of your code? Is the ONNX exported model generated to disk? The model can be loaded properly?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is given directly in the warning message. Since PyTorch1.10, the floordiv is deprecated. You need to update `input.size(1) // num_groups` to `torch.div(input.size(1), num_groups, rounding_mode='floor')` if you wish to avoid the warning.

But it is indeed weird that the `//` should be considered as `torch. floor_divide` only when a torch.Tensor is included as operand. This might has something to do with the onnx export logic. Hopefully someone more familar with the underlying logic could give a deeper answer.